# MSAL error when Authenticating to MS GRAPH in IE

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, msal.js

I'm trying to authenticate into MS Graph via MSAL and ReactJs. Problem is it fails in IE when I try to login. I've attached an image of the error I'm getting when login.

[image]

The login occurs when I make a request to "userAgentApplication.loginPopup"

```
try {
    await this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup(
        {
        scopes: scopes,
        prompt: "select_account"
    });

}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('failed');
}
```

I disabled popup blocker on Internet Options but I still have the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The site is blocking the MSAL popup.You can allow it by going to  **Tools -> Internet Options -> Privacy->Pop-up Blocker Settings** and adding your site.

[image]

Also, please refer [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-known-issues-ie-edge-browsers) if you still face any issue.